# Epimorphism of sets is a surjective function

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

An epimorphism as a function $f\colon A\to B$ such that for all sets $Z$ and all functions $\alpha,\alpha'\colon B\to Z$,
$$\alpha\circ f = \alpha'\circ f \implies \alpha = \alpha'.$$
We give a proof of the fact that every epimorphism is a surjective function.

\begin{proof}
We reason via contradiction and assume $f\colon A\to B$ is an epimorphism that is not a surjection.

Consider the functions $\alpha,\alpha'\colon B\to \{0,1\}$ defined by
$$(\forall b\in B)(\alpha(b) = 1) $$
$$\alpha'(b) = 
\begin{cases}
1 &&\text{if $b \in f(A)$} \\
0 &&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Now, let $a\in A,$ then
$$
\alpha\circ f(a) = \alpha(f(a)) = 1
$$
and
$$
\alpha'\circ f(a) = \alpha'(f(a)) = 1
$$
noting that $f(a) \in f(A).$ Hence, $\alpha\circ f = \alpha\circ f$ so using the fact that $f$ is
an epimorphism, we conclude that $\alpha = \alpha'.$
However, $f$ is not surjective therefore there exists at least one element $b_0 \in B\setminus f(A).$ By definition of $\alpha$ and $\alpha', $ we have
$$\alpha(b_0) = 1$$
and
$$ \alpha(b_0) = 0.$$ But $\alpha = \alpha'$ so $$ 1 = \alpha(b_0) = \alpha'(b_0) = 0 $$ which is
a contradiction. Hence $f$ is surjective and we are done.

Please see if the proof is correct and whether it can be rewritten in a better manner. The way I came up with the proof was somewhat haphazard (I mostly thought about how we need to find 2 functions that agree on f(A) but disagree otherwise to get a contradiction) and was wondering (as this is my first time learning this subject) whether proofs like this are usually come up in such a haphazard manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof is correct, indeed!

I guess it's a matter of taste, but there's no need of using a contradiction argument. In summary, I would just say: "pick $\alpha,\alpha'$ as you defined, then $\alpha \circ f = \alpha' \circ f$, and the fact that $f$ is an epimorphism implies $\alpha = \alpha'$, which is equivalent to $f(A)=B$".

There's no simpler proof, though. If you learn more math in the future, this proof will not be so weird to you. For instance, if you want to show the analogous result for modules or groups instead of just sets, the map $\alpha'$ you want to consider is the natural map $A \to A/f(A)$. The $\alpha'$ of your proof is the set-theoretical version of this map.

$\textbf{Remark.}$ As you may know, the converse of the result is also true! (and easier to prove).

Comment: This was actually one side of the equivalence of epimorphisms of sets and surjective functions! The other side is easier because of the existence of right inverses which we can operate to conclude that the function is an epimorphism. My initial idea was to give a direct argument but I was not sure whether $\alpha = \alpha'$ is enough to conclude $f(A) = B.$ Thank you very much!

Comment: @ChiragKar You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Assumption: ''We reason via contradiction and assume f:A→B is an epimorphism''

You don't need that $f$ is not surjective here.

Conclusion: ''Hence, α∘f=α∘f so using the fact that f is an epimorphism, we conclude that α=α′.''

From this, $f(A)=B$ follows.

Comment: I was initially going for a direct argument as well but I was not sure whether to conclude that $\alpha = \alpha'$ is equivalent to $f(A) = B. $  Thinking about this again, I can see that a direct proof is simpler. Thank you very much!